# Create a custom map

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, gps, location-services

I'm finding a way which how to create a custom map. Assuming I have a drawing design of my building. I want to locate my current position in that building. That map is just for my building. I use 3G or wifi to get my current position

Do you know how to create a kind of that mini map, with an exact location?

Thank you so much,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's basically just this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple

So you make an image with the blueprints.  Rotate the blueprint inside the image, so the top of the image faces north.

Then you must know the coordinates of the edges of your image.

---

As an example, I show the White house (Washington DC, USA).

Here is the image: http://www.whitehousemuseum.org/images/floor2-c1880.jpg

boundaries of that image, I estimated as [38.897449233423366,-77.03687542676926] to [38.897958578125014,-77.03614050149918].  It's not exactly correct, feel free to estimate better than me.

The only code I changed (as oposed to the link I gave you), is within function initMap() .

Then I also added function geoFindMe(), to get your current position.  It puts a marker on your current position.

Notice:

geolocation is not a Google Maps service.  It's a service of your phone/tablet/...

The accuracy will not be perfect.  For a normal house you might see the marker in a wrong room.  The bigger the building, the better.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Adding a Custom Overlay</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 400px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?"></script>
    <script>
var overlay;
USGSOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 18,
    center: {lat: 38.89765946197239, lng: -77.03650183923475},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  });

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
      new google.maps.LatLng(38.897449233423366,-77.03687542676926),
      new google.maps.LatLng(38.897958578125014,-77.03614050149918)
  );

  var srcImage = 'http://www.whitehousemuseum.org/images/floor2-c1880.jpg';  // the white house, Washington DC
  overlay = new USGSOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map);
  // geolocation
  geoFindMe();
}

function USGSOverlay(bounds, image, map) {
  this.bounds_ = bounds;
  this.image_ = image;
  this.map_ = map;
  this.div_ = null;
  this.setMap(map);
}

USGSOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
  div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
  div.style.position = 'absolute';

  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = this.image_;
  img.style.width = '100%';
  img.style.height = '100%';
  img.style.position = 'absolute';
  div.appendChild(img);

  this.div_ = div;

  var panes = this.getPanes();
  panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
};

USGSOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {

  var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();

  var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
  var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());

  var div = this.div_;
  div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
  div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
  div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
  div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
};
USGSOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() {
  this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
  this.div_ = null;
};
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);

// Geolocation.  Finds your location and puts a marker on a map, on that position
// @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation
function geoFindMe() {
  var output = document.getElementById("log");
  if (!navigator.geolocation){
    output.innerHTML = "<p>Geolocation is not supported by your browser</p>";
    return;
  }

  function success(position) {
    var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    // set a marker there
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: latitude,lng: longitude},
      map: map,
      title: 'You are here'
    });
  };

  function error() {
    output.innerHTML = "Unable to retrieve your location";
  };
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="log"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```